# Understanding slice in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Consider the following string:

```
const str = "I am a good boy"
```

> At, index 7 = g
>   At, indedx 10 = d
>   But when I use, splice method for strings, which accept two parameters ie start index, end index, so when I use

```
const result = str.slice(7, 10)
console.log(result)
```

I am expecting it to return `good` but it only returns `goo` Why is that so, even at index 10, d is present?

According to W3 Schools

> slice() extracts a part of a string and returns the extracted part in
>   a new string.
>
> The method takes 2 parameters: the starting index (position), and the
>   ending index (position).

Comment: `splice()` or `slice()` ?

Comment: It only goes **up** to the index, but **does not** include it.

Comment: On a side note, prefer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) to W3Schools.

Comment: Thank you, I got the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), the `endIndex` (second) parameter is the index *before which* to end extraction from the source string.

It's useful to have the end index be one place after the desired content because it makes doing math a little easier. If you want three characters starting at position `i`, you can use `source.slice(i, i+3)`.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like how range works in maths, there are ones with inclusive boundaries and ones whose boundaries are not included i.e. a range could be one of the following,

- closed range - (1, 10) i.e. range 2 - 9, doesn't include indices 1 and 10
- opened range - [1, 10] i.e. range 1 - 10, includes 1 and 10.
- half opened - [1, 10) or (1, 10] i.e. the first range starts from 1 but ends at 9, the second starts at 2 and ends at 10.

so the splice function takes a half opened range of the form [a, b) for which it includes the first but is closed at the lower boundary i.e. it doesn't include the lower boundary.

Comment: That's why math is *always* important. :)

Comment: Lol, that is the root of all explanations.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this. If you think of them as the places where the letters should start it makes perfect sense.

[image]